# How to aggregate Micrometer metrics from multiple instances of the same microservice

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I've configured Micrometer + Prometheus in a Spring Boot application deployed on Kubernetes. This application will have multiple instances that will be measuring some business processes using tags:

`process1.calls.total`
`process1.calls.successful`
`process1.calls.failed`

I'd like to generate a Grafana dashboard that aggregates the metrics across all the instances of the microservice:

**instance 1**

`process1.calls.total=20`

`process1.calls.successful=10`

`process1.calls.failed=10`

**instance 2**

`process1.calls.total=5`

`process1.calls.successful=2`

`process1.calls.failed=3`

The dashboard should show:

`Process1 Total calls: 25`

`Process1 Successful calls: 12`

`Process1 Successful calls: 13`

How can I aggregate them?

Comment: IIUC, you cannot aggregate across instances using Prometheus|Grafana using your current approach. With Prometheus, aggregation across metrics requires that you relax|omit dimensions (labels). In your case, you probably (!) want to use `instance` (`process`) as a label (in micrometer these are called "tags"). Then you can query by calls on a specific instance (`calls_total{instance="instance-1"}`) and you can summarize calls across instances (`sum without(instance) (calls_total)`). You likely need to only record `total` and `failed` metrics since (`success=total-failed`).

Comment: See Micrometer [concepts](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts) specifically 6. Naming Meters and 6.1. Tag Naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish your time series per instance; add some sort of instance identifier like host+port or appname+host or pod-name.

That way your time series will look like this:

```
process1_calls_total{instance="001"} 2.0
process1_calls_total{instance="002"} 3.0
process1_calls_total{instance="003"} 5.0
```

Using `process1_calls_total` in your queries without specifying `instance` will give you an aggregate across your instances. PLease also check the prometheus docs for this.